# Possible to write to the console from a separate thread than the Main() one? Or what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I have the following basic for my `console application`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Attempt at a DNS attack
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        for(;;;)
        {
            HttpWebResponse resp = await DoSomethingAsync();
            await Task.Delay(50);
        }
    });
}

static void PrintResponseToConsole(HttpWebResponse response)
{
    // ... Console.WriteLine some stuff
}
```

however when I run it I don't see anything. How can I do this better?

Comment: where are you calling the method that prints to console?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad In `PrintResponseToConsole`, as the name implies

Comment: where you call the `PrintResponseToConsole` in your code?

Comment: Should we really help writing "DNS attack" code?

Comment: You must either wait on Task (e.g. `Task.Run(async() => {...}).Wait()`, or use another way to block main thread (e.g. `Console.ReadKey()`), otherwise main thread immediately exits and application closes.

Comment: @SirRufo Yes. The code in itself has no moral connotation. It is the **USE** that is "good" or "evil". For a [pen test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penetration_test) this is perfectly legit, legal and good. On the other hand, if he uses it to attack others property... well, that's evil and should be punished to its full extent.

Answer (score 1):

You can write to the console from any thread. The `Console` type has internal locking specifically to support multithreaded access.

Your main thread is probably exiting immediately; you'll need to block `Main` until you're ready to exit. E.g.:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Task.Run(async () =>
  {
    for(;;;)
    {
      HttpWebResponse resp = await DoSomethingAsync();
      await Task.Delay(50);
    }
  });
  Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing one line where you actually call the `PrintResponseToConsole()` method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Attempt at a DNS attack
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        for(;;;)
        {
            HttpWebResponse resp = await DoSomethingAsync();
            PrintResponseToConsole(resp); // <---------- THIS LINE
            await Task.Delay(50);
        }
    });
}
```